# Unexpected indent error in Django Log Object

Tags: python, django

Im have a Django application and Im adding Django log Object to it, Im following this documentation 
https://code.osuosl.org/projects/django-object-log/wiki/Usage#Registering-Action-Types

I'm in the part of adding log entries in the documentation
which gives the following example of how to add log in a def method, here is the example:

```
 # store log_action for faster access
 log = LogItem.objects.log_action

 def my_view(request, pk):
     """ example view that retrieves an object by its pk """ 
     obj = SomeModel.objects.get(pk=pk)
     log('MY_EVENT', request.user, obj)
```

tasks.py is a view in my application this is a def where I want to add the log call

```
def edit_task(request, task_id):
    t = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=task_id)
    t.category = request.POST['cat_dd']
    t.subcategory = request.POST['subcat_dd']
    t.name = request.POST['task_name']
    t.description = request.POST['task_desc']
    t.country = request.POST['country_dd']
    t.city = request.POST['task_city']
    t.address = request.POST['task_address']
    t.status = request.POST['status_dd']

    log('MY_EVENT', request.user, t)

    if (employer_id == NULL or getcategory == "Please select a category" or getsubcategory == "Please select a subcategory" or getname == "" or getdesc == "Write a short description about your task.." or getcountry == "(please select a country)" or getcity == "" or getaddress == "" or getstatus == ""):
        return render_to_response('editTask.html',RequestContext(request))
    else:
        t = Task.objects.create(employer = employer_id, category = getcategory, subcategory = getsubcategory, name = getname, description = getdesc, country = getcountry, city = getcity, address = getaddress, status = getstatus, contractor = NULL)
        t.save()

        return render_to_response('task.html',RequestContext(request))
```

after adding this line `log('MY_EVENT', request.user, t)` in the previous code I got an error

I got an error `unexpected indent (tasks.py, line 58)`

what could be the reason for that error ??

Comment: Have you double checked space/tab indenting?

Comment: is line 58 the line with `log('MY_EVENT', request.user, t)`? If so, can you check for tabs, or other invisble indentation? (sometimes a problem with copy and paste)

Comment: Don't see any indentation errors, but there's no such thing as `NULL` in Python.

Comment: Thank you I used spaces instead of tabs and it works

Comment: Now I have another problem, when I added the following lines in my code. def build_cache(user, obj1, obj2, obj3, data):
      return {'foo':obj.foo}
 I got an error "name 'register' is not defined"
 register('MY_EVENT', 'template.html', build_cache)

Comment: See my answer below. 'register' isn't a function that you can import, it's a method of LogActionManager (accessed via LogAction.objects)

Answer (score 1):

You've most likely mixed tabs and spaces in your source file. You can check that manually, or a tool like pyflakes can do it for you, automatically.

And for your error about the register function you need to call:

```
 from object_log.models import LogAction
 LogAction.objects.register('MY_EVENT','template.html', build_cache)
```